# Set application status bar colors

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I wrote a service with implementations per platform, to change the color of the StatusBar for my application.

Currently, each ContentPage will have to set its own color, in xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyApp.Helpers"
             helpers:StatusBarHelper.StatusBarColor="{StaticResource MyColor}">
```

Where the helper calls the service with the specified color.

Otherwise, the color will remain from the previous page that set it.

What I want is that the StatusBar will receive the same color as the page's background.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the following solution

#### in Forms

```
public interface IStatusBarStyleManager
{
    void SetColoredStatusBar(string hexColor);
   
}
```

Setup the Status bar color with this line

```
DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarStyleManager>().SetColoredStatusBar("#2196F3");
```

#### in Android

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(StatusBarStyleManager))]
namespace ShaXam.Droid.DependencyServices
{
    public class StatusBarStyleManager : IStatusBarStyleManager
    {
        public void SetColoredStatusBar(string hexColor)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var currentWindow = GetCurrentWindow();
                    currentWindow.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
                    currentWindow.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(hexColor);
                });
            }
        }

        public void SetWhiteStatusBar()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var currentWindow = GetCurrentWindow();
                    currentWindow.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
                    currentWindow.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                });
            }
        }

        Window GetCurrentWindow()
        {
            var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;

            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

            return window;
        }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StatusBarStyleManager))]
namespace ShaXam.iOS.DependencyServices
{
    public class StatusBarStyleManager : IStatusBarStyleManager
    {
        public void SetColoredStatusBar(string hexColor)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
                {
                    UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
                    statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(hexColor).ToUIColor();
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
                }
                else
                {
                    UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
                    if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
                    {
                        statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(hexColor).ToUIColor();
                    }
                }
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
                GetCurrentViewController().SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
            });
        }

        public void SetWhiteStatusBar()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
                {
                    UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
                    statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
                }
                else
                {
                    UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
                    if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
                    {
                        statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    }
                }
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.DarkContent, false);
                GetCurrentViewController().SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
            });
        }

        UIViewController GetCurrentViewController()
        {
            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var vc = window.RootViewController;
            while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
                vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
            return vc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. My question was more like: Do I need to keep calling DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarStyleManager>().SetColoredStatusBar("#2196F3"); for each and every page I navigate to, or is there a better way? Maybe some way to sample the first pixel's color at the top of the page and adjust the StatusBar color to it?

Comment: You could create a base ContentPage so that you only need to  set it once .

Comment: I get null ref exception on var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;